Uses for the TPS Tiles after shuttle
After the space shuttle’s retirement, what has the technology seen with the orbiters thermal protection system (TPS Tiles) had a use for post 2011, since to my knowledge no other vehicles are using such technology on their rocket designs

Starship has a tile heatshield. So does Dream Chaser.

The US Air Force/Space Force operate the X37 spaceplane that uses tiles as part of its TPS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_X-37#Design.  The Chinese have something similar and ISRO have one in development.

One problem with the Shuttle tile system was that the shape of each tile was unique, which makes them more expensive to produce, and annoying to assemble. But as the Vegreville egg guys discovered, it can be possible to tile various curved surfaces with (mostly) congruent tiles.

Tiles TPS is a labour intensive process,  old but a reliable method with proven TPS materials adaptation. This method is still selected either in the form of Silica, cork Phenolic or other TPM. Many SLVs adopt this style specially on Payload Fairing Protection. TPS spray is another stylish way of it which covers all disadvantages of Tiled system but can't eliminate it due to lower temperature limits and process qualification restrictions.

this is a good start for an answer, but it would be very helpful if you added citations and links to references with more information.

I see no reference to shuttle-style tiles in this answer.
